# Parsing second level in nested JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I've been looking around and there seem to be some examples on how to do similar things to this one, but I've tried different approaches and haven't come with a working solution.

I have this JSON file:

```
 [
  {
    "name": "tool 1",
    "basic":[{
      "description": "text",
      "color": "red"
    }]
  },

  {
    "name": "tool 2",
    "basic":[{
      "description": "text",
      "color": "red"
    }]
  }
]
```

So I'm using jQuery to parse it, and my code looks like this:

```
$.getJSON("/js/data.json", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {
    console.log(val.name);
  });
});
```

It works well for the first level item, such as "name"; but if I want to do the same with "description" and "color" does not seem to work, without doing an individual "each…" for each one, inside the main one.

I'm trying to find a simple and elegant solution such as:

```
console.log(val.basic.color);
```

But it doesn't seem to work ("undefined".)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since `val.basic` is an array, you need to loop over it.

```
$.getJSON("/js/data.json", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {
    console.log(val.name);
    $.each(val.basic, function(index, basic) {
      console.log(basic.description, basic.color);
    });
  });
});
```

If you only care about the first element, you can index it instead:

```
console.log(val.basic[0].description, val.basic[0].color);
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe my JSON is not formatted correctly then. I did it this way so I could identify certain hierarchy / sub-levels, and group values. But I'd rather prefer to be able to access each item, independently of the level where it its, without having to loop again. Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: Don't put it in an array if there's only one item. Make it `"basic": { "description": "text", "color": "red" }`. Then your original attempt would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar, I wanted to post the solution for anyone else.

This is how the JSON is formatted now, removing the `[]` to remove the array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "tool 1",
    "basic_info":{
      "description": "text 1",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    "advanced":{
      "description": "text 1 advanced",
      "color": "blue advanced"
    }
  },

  {
    "name": "tool 2",
    "basic_info":{
      "description": "text 1",
      "color": "red"
    },
    "advanced":{
      "description": "text 2 advanced",
      "color": "red advanced"
    }
  }
]
```

And this is the code I'm using to access a second-level value:

```
$.getJSON("/js/data.json", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {
    console.log(val.basic_info.color);
  });
});
```